# Angular2-Material Change md-input style on errors

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would, in case of error on my form, change the label of my input as well as the text color and border-color below, much like with dividerColor, but without focus, I'd like that persistent.

So I made this code there for the label:

```
md-input:not(.ng-valid) label { background-color: red !important; color:red !important; }
```

However, when I run the project, my css is modified in this way:

```
md-input[_ngcontent-fcu-13]:not(.ng-valid) label[_ngcontent-fcu-13] { background-color: red !important; color:red !important; }
```

And therefore, it does not work.
Do you have an idea ?
(Translated by google translation)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this styles outside of components' tree in which you describe it?
Attributes like _ngcontent-fcu-13 angular adds to DOM elements and styles to implement [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html). So if you import styles as part of component metadata angular will add such attributes to all styles.

You should move global styles to the app.component or inject them directly into the index.html.

Also you can turn off View Encapsulation by adding

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

into component's metadata

Take a look at this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html). it helps me a lot.